# bootstrap navbar opens upward

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a navbar in bootstrap 3 for a client's website. For some reason, however, the navbar opens upward on a mobile interface, throwing parts of it off the screen.

```
<div id="mainWrapper">
    <div id="navbar" class="row">
            <div id="mainLogo" class="col-xs-3"><p class="bottom-text">LOGO PLACEHODER</p></div>
            <div id="spacer" class="col-xs-3"></div>
            <div id="menu" class="col-xs-6">
                <nav id="rightnav" class="navbar navbar-default bottom-text">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                            <div>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
                            </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tonykuroi/5n8fcwmv/

The thing about this is that while I know the CSS is a bit weird (and frankly ugly) - I need to make the website look a specific way. The client is an artist, and she is completely resistant to any change to her design.

What I am looking for is a way for it to push the content down rather than push itself up.

Can anyone see something that might be contributing to the weird behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by this class

```
.bottom-text{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Fix it to something like:

```
.bottom-text{
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Not so much "fix" as "cover it up with"

Comment: yeah, I was thinking about doing something like this. The only issue was I didnt really want to be using margins like that, just in case something weird were to happen with the navbar. That said, it's not like the height of the navbar should be changing ANYHOW, but it was a "just in case" that I wanted to prepare for.

Comment: Right, you have a fixed height div so that shouldn't cause problems. Ofc there may be more elegant solution.

Comment: Well for reference I ended up going with a solution like this. I'm just going to do a lot of testing with different sizes. I wish I had found something a bit better though.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this portion:

```
<nav id="rightnav" class="navbar navbar-default bottom-text">
```

to

```
<nav id="rightnav" class="navbar navbar-default top-text">
```

`bottom-text` change to `top-text`.

http://jsfiddle.net/5n8fcwmv/2/

Comment: This changes the position of the menu on the layout.

Comment: He can customize the the other classes to achieve his style. This should be the bootstrap class that he need for displaying the mobile menu downwards.

Answer (score -2):

Bootstrap is a responsive CSS framework; the menu will take another form in mobile screens, so you do not need any additional CSS to do so. See a simple example:

```css
p {
    color:white;
}
/******************** IDs **********************/
 #contentPane {
}
#mainWrapper {
    max-width:775px;
    background-color:black;
}
#navbar {
    margin:0px;
    max-width:775px;
    height:120px;
    background:url('../images/top_background.jpg') no-repeat;
}
#rightnav {
    right:0;
}
#spacer {
    height:100%;
}
#menu {
    height:100%;
}
#mainLogo {
    height:100%
}
#footerText {
    text-align:right;
    margin-top:15px;
}
#footer {
    height:50px;
}
/**************** Classes **********************/
 .row {
    position:relative;
}
.bottom-text {
    padding-top: 70px;
}
.navbar, .navbar-default, .nav, .navbar-nav {
    background-color:transparent;
    border-color:transparent;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
.active {
    background-color:transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainWrapper">
    <div id="navbar" class="row">
        <div id="mainLogo" class="col-xs-3">
            <p class="bottom-text">LOGO PLACEHOLDER</p>
        </div>
        <div id="spacer" class="col-xs-3"></div>
        <div id="menu" class="col-xs-6">
            <nav id="rightnav" class="navbar navbar-default top-text">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                        <div>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have removed all of OP's styles. This isn't a solution; you need to account for his styles.

Comment: sorry I posted a wrong content , please check this one